# Update Function Updating All Records Instead of One

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form I am building in Access that helps manage records for a table. I have an EDIT function that when it runs it fills the text boxes with the designated information then I click an update button to change the information and resave the data, when I do this though instead of just updating the one record, it updates all the records that have the corresponding data I am updating EXAMPLE: If I change an employees readiness level from READY NOW to RETAIN, it will change all the READY NOWs in the table to RETAIN instead of just the one. Any ideas on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

THe code is below

```
Private Sub cmdEdit_Click()
'check whether there exists data in the list
If Not (Me.frmCDDataSub.Form.Recordset.EOF And Me.frmCDDataSub.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then
    'get data to text box control
    With Me.frmCDDataSub.Form.Recordset
        Me.txtEmpID = .Fields("EmployeeID")
        Me.txtEmpName = .Fields("EmployeeName")
        Me.cboGender = .Fields("Gender")
        Me.cboEEOC = .Fields("EEOC")
        Me.cboReadyLvl = .Fields("ReadinessLevel")
        Me.cboDivision = .Fields("Division")
        Me.txtCenter = .Fields("Center")
        Me.txtFeedback = .Fields("EmployeeFeedback")
        Me.txtDevelopment = .Fields("DevelopmentForEmployee")
        Me.txtJustification = .Fields("Justification")
        Me.cboChanged = .Fields("Changed")
        'store id of employee in tag of text id in case id is modified
        Me.txtEmpID.Tag = .Fields("EmployeeID")
        'change caption of button add to update
        Me.cmdAdd.Caption = "Update"
        'disable edit button
        Me.cmdEdit.Enabled = False
End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any "update" code in your question, so it's difficult to see what the cuase of the problem might be.

Comment: So this is the portion that populates your textboxes prior to the edit - ?  But the error occurs when you run the update?  Tim is right this shouldn't make any changes to your table data at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Access was designed specifically to avoid having to code what you are doing. Unless there is a specific reason why you are doing this explicitly, field by field, you can avoid all this code by simply setting your form to the appropriate source (i.e. table) and then each of your controls should be assigned to a field using the ControlSource property (I forget the name exactly).

You are not showing us your Update code. You need to show us this code since it's updating your entire table. This is where the problem is. But as I mentioned, you should avoid this sort of explicit assignment of each field (unless there is something you are not telling us).

The only time I ever had to explicitly do this is if each field had to be manipulated or changed right before saving, and it doesn't seem to me that you are doing this.